# I have installed module "cst" but the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cst'" still exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use CST 2021 and Python 3.8.10, and I have Python 3.10 as well. I installed "cst" module in Python 3.8.10 but the error still exists.

Comment: The module is found in the "Python38\Lib\site-packages"

Comment: You have 2 python versions installed 3.8.10 and 3.10. If the package is installed for python3.8 as per your comment and you still get the error, that means you are using python3.10 to run whatever code produce the error

Comment: I select python 3.8.10 when I was creating the new project. It should be the correct version importing the module